# Writing a decimal fraction in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

The best way to show my issue is to discuss the following example in Python:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
a = [[1.2,1.23,1.234,np.float(5.678),np.float(2/3.)]]
with open('afile.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    output = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    #output.writerows(fwithenergies)
    for row in a:
        output.writerow(row)
```

then in the afile.csv file I get:

> 1.2   1.23    1234    5678    6,66666666666667E+15

in different columns.

I have two question:

1. why a dot disappears in the `1234` and `5678` expressions
2. how to convert 6,66666666666667E+15 to the form e.g. 6.66667

I have tried a lot of examples from the Internet but nothing works for me.

Comment: this is what I get in csv file and it seems ok : **1.2,1.23,1.234,5.678,0.6666666666666666**  and that seems ok.  Have tried it in python2 and python3

Comment: I have tried 2 and 3 and the same

Comment: what program you are  using to open the csv file?

Comment: LibreOffice calc. I can check later in Excel. Wow I have checked in leafpad and get 1.2,1.23,1.234,5.678,0.6666666666666666. So problem was in another place. Thanks a lot for a tip!

Comment: yes, LibreOffice seems to mess up and loads your data in a weird way.